# why my slide nav bar keep expanding even i dont trigger it

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

please take a look to this. i tired use
media min-width 768px sidebar-wrapper and sidebar-nav li a, display: none, but that slide nav keep showing (auto expand), even the button to trigger that nav already gone.
[image]
every time i refresh/open with desktop

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;

      }


.navbar li a {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
  color: gray !important;
}
.navbar-inner,
.navbar .btn-navbar {
  background: #ffffff
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #333;
  float: left;
}

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: auto;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}



#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/respond.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" id="menu-toggle" style=" margin-left: 24px;"> 
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>


    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i> Youtube Channel</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav> <!-- end navigation button-->

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand" >
                    <a href="#">
                        sad
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">a<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu navmenu-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">a1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">a2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">a3</a></li>
                  
                </ul>
            </li>
               
                <li>
                    <a href="#" >About</a>
                </li>
                
               
                    </ul>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">

    </div>

</nav> 


        </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

and

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

For your second problem: I cant find a `display: none;` in your CSS.

auto-expand problem:

set `width: 250px;` for the standard width of your nav.
in your media-queries work with

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar-wrapper {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

and change your jquery-code to

```
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0px;
}
```

this is not tested, but you should get the idea.
always show the navbar at start, hide it when screen is <768px with `display: none;`, this way it doesnt get animated.
and change the toggle to work with the new standard width.

Comment: yeah thanks, problem 1 solved :D, yup, i erase that code because that not work, here i update the code with display none, and why you should not do this? i think this website suppose to be where we ask and learn, its my 1st project tho, i write the code while watch and reading tutorial from internet only, that why i always seems ask stupid question for advance ppl like you :)

Comment: its ok to use `display: none;`, i was talking about the `position` of the divs. `absolute` and `relative` positioning usually only work inside another `relative` positioned div, but you messed it up in your first version. CSS looks much better now, too, you combined the @media. Do you still have a Question? Your navigation seems to work now as expected, or do i miss something?

Comment: umm there's one last problem, that navigation keep auto expand while i load the page in desktop screen size, ill be glad if you can give me another advice how to prevent that auto expand thing happen, thanks for lesson tho :)

Comment: can you show me this page or a snippet with this code? i cant reproduce that.

Comment: exactly the same code with my post, try open it with full screen mode and you will see the problem

Comment: ok, i didnt realize that you had a problem with the auto-expand. i added some lines to my answer for it.

Comment: thank you so much for what you already tech me, i really learn a lot from you, thanks